# Создать новый стек со значениями из другого стека

Tags: c++

Создать стек с числами в диапазоне от –50 до +50.  После создания стека выполнить индивидуальное задание. В конце работы все стеки должны быть удалены.

Индивидуальное задание: Создать новый стек, содержащий только те числа из первого стека, которые больше среднего значения всех элементов первого стека.

Вот мой код:

```
using namespace std;

struct Stack
{
    int info;
    Stack (*next);
}*begin1;
Stack* InStack(Stack*, int);
void View(Stack*);
void mima(Stack*);

int main()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 101; i++)
    {
        begin1 = InStack(begin1, rand() % 101 - 50);
    }
    View(begin1);
    mima(begin1);
    getchar();
}

Stack* InStack(Stack *p, int in){
    Stack *t = new Stack;
    t->info = in;
    t->next = p;
    return t;
}

void View(Stack *p)
{
    Stack *t = p;
    while (t != NULL)
    {
        cout « t->info « "\n";
        t = t->next;
    }
}

void mima(Stack *p)
{
    Stack *temp = p;
    int sum = 0, num = 0;
    cout « endl;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        num++;
        sum += temp->info;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    sum /= num;
    temp = p;
    cout « "Count=" « sum « endl;
}
```

Comment: проблему опишите

Comment: Я высчитал среднее значение элементов первого стека. Теперь нужно во второй стек добавить значения первого стека которые больше среднего значения. Я не знаю как это сделать, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: sum  у вас среднее значение содержит: Создавайте такой же стэк, где  info > sum

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Stack {
    int info;
    Stack (*next);
} *begin1, *second;

Stack *InStack(Stack *, int);

void View(Stack *);

void mima(Stack *, int &);

Stack *moreAverage(Stack *p, Stack *&second, int average);

int main() {
    int i; int average = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= 101; i++) {
        begin1 = InStack(begin1, rand() % 101 - 50);
    }
    View(begin1);
    mima(begin1, average);

    cout << "average = " << average << endl;

    moreAverage(begin1, second, average);

    View(second);

}

Stack *moreAverage(Stack *p, Stack *&second, int average){
    Stack *t;

    while (p != NULL){
        if(p->info > average){
            Stack *tmp = new Stack;
            tmp->info = p->info;

            if(second == NULL){
                second = tmp;
                t = second; // запоминаем начало для нового списка
            } else{
                // добавляем новые элементы
                second ->next = tmp;
                second = second ->next;
            }
        }
        p = p->next;
    }

    second = t; // возвращаем указатель на начало, так как сейчас сылается на конец списка 
}

Stack *InStack(Stack *p, int in) {
    Stack *t = new Stack;
    t->info = in;
    t->next = p;
    return t;
}

void View(Stack *p) {
    Stack *t = p;
    while (t != NULL) {
        cout<< t->info << "\n";
        t = t->next;
    }
}

void mima(Stack *p, int &average) {
    Stack *temp = p;
    int sum = 0, num = 0;
    cout << endl;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        num++;
        sum += temp->info;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    sum /= num;
    average = sum;
    temp = p;
    cout << "Count=" << sum << endl;
}
```

вывод

-21
-15
7
8
17
-25
19
-3
-6
-7
-1
36
14
-11
-8
-42
11
-33
-3
-1
37
-35
-4
-10
-4
18
13
-19
13
19
7
15
12
-24
6
-35
-45
28
-11
43
45
22
3
-14
38
29
50
-34
48
-32
-25
35
27
9
26
33
8
-27
-17
28
24
-38
-20
38
33
-3
30
17
31
-42
11
21
-1
-37
-28
11
29
-33
12
11
-23
49
25
-1
-45
-46
25
13
-21
-27
-13
19
28
-39
22
-35
-31
-9
-19
15
-9

Count=1
average = 1

7
8
17
19
36
14
11
37
18
13
13
19
7
15
12
6
28
43
45
22
3
38
29
50
48
35
27
9
26
33
8
28
24
38
33
30
17
31
11
21
11
29
12
11
49
25
25
13
19
28
22
15

Comment: А из-за чего может быть вот эта проблема, я полностью скопировал код чтоб проверить и переделать error C4716: moreAverage: должна возвращать значение